# Can't run Google apps script, error 401: disabled_client

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Sheets document that has a script attached to it and this AppScript includes a function that runs on a trigger every hour. The script fills in the sheet with importrange-formulas to get data from other sheets. It's been running fine for 6 months, but today I got an error.

The scheduled script has stopped running. When I try to manually run the function I get authorization request, and when I try to grant the script permission to run I get "Error 401: disabled_client".
I have similar scripts running in  other Google Sheets document on similar trigger settings, and those keep running just fine. All the scripts are running on the same enterprise account.
Any ideas what can be going on here?

Grateful for any help to solve this.

Comment: have you assigned a Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Project to your script, or you use the default one?

Comment: I use the default. Never used GCP for any script. Don´t know how GCP works

Comment: Try to make a copy of the document and run the script copy. I had some weird situations in the past where such a "reset" helped

Comment: Already tried it. Logged out and in of Google, re-opened the sheets, nothing works so far

Comment: Found a solution, although I think this only works temporarily.
Made a copy of the document, deleted all scripts, and then attached all scripts again.
Then I got the authorization request again, and this time it worked